# To make beep and font size big for EPOS printer

Tags: android, printing, fonts, size, beep

I developed an android application for a restaurant. I use escape code to cut paper after print. I want to make beep before printing and text should be big font size. There is escape code of beep and font size for E-POS printer.
I use escape code to make beep and font size big. But not success. From Desktop application which is developed by VB can make beep and big size text from this printer. Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

**E-POS printer model:TEP-220MD**

I use escape code for

**Beep:**

```
byte bel = 0x07;
oStream.write(bel);
```

**font size:**

```
oStream.println(new char[]{0x1B,0x21, 0x10}
```

This code is not working.Where I mistake.

Comment: no, this code does not work for beep. but this is the escape code for beep.

Comment: for big font size I use this code: oStream.println(new char[]{0x1B,0x21, 0x18}) and It works. But I do find any esc command for Beep. do you have any idea.